# Error: Cannot find module '../build/Debug/sqlclient'

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb, mariasql

In directory i did the standard- npm install mariasql --save.
when i run my server file -node app.js.
It returns an error like this:

```
 Error: Cannot find module '../build/Debug/sqlclient'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/asa/Dropbox/justRent/development/node_modules/mariasql/lib/Client.js:12:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: have you include this module in your main file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this is not issue from node side, please Check your db sever is receiving connection from all the host, if not set the privileges correctly as using `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'DBPASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;` from the default user table, after set this try to reinstall the maria sql package in node and give a try.